# unable to set variable in case statement bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to set a variable based on a bunch of input conditions.  Here's a small sample of the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_SIZE=""
case "$1" in
   "micro")
     $INSTANCE_SIZE="t1.micro"
     ;;
   "small")
     $INSTANCE_SIZE="m1.small"

     ;;
esac
echo $INSTANCE_SIZE
```

When I run the script with the -ex switch and specify the proper argument:

```
+ case "$1" in
+ =m1.small
./provision: line 19: =m1.small: command not found
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` sign in the assignments - `INSTANCE_SIZE="m1.small"`. With the dollar sign, `$INSTANCE_SIZE` gets substituted with its value and no assignment takes place - bash rather tries to execute the command that resulted from the interpolation.